# How automatically access a specific column of matrix variables in a data frame?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, variable-assignment

I have a data frame in which many variables are matrices that share similar column names for their own columns. I want to apply a function to a specific column of all variables.

The following code is a sample of data and a try to do so. However, I get an error when trying to access a column using a name generated by `paste()` function.

```
data_all <- data.frame(time=sample(seq(1, 20), 1000, replace=TRUE), A= runif(1000), B= runif(1000))
str(data_all)
data_all_agg <- data.frame(aggregate(list(A = data_all[, 'A']), list(time = data_all[, 'time']), function (x) quantile(x, probs = c(0.2, 0.5, 0.8)) ))
data_all_agg <- cbind(data_all_agg, data.frame(aggregate(list(B = data_all[, 'B']), list(time = data_all[, 'time']), function (x) quantile(x, probs = c(0.2, 0.5, 0.8)) )))
data_all_agg <- data_all_agg[!duplicated(lapply(data_all_agg, summary))]
#
var_names <- c("A", "B")
for (var_name_counter in c(1:2)) {
        get(paste("data_all_agg$", var_names[var_name_counter],"[,\"50%\"]", sep=""))
}

Error in get(paste("data_all_agg$", var_names[var_name_counter], "[,\"50%\"]",  : 
      object 'data_all_agg$A[,"50%"]' not found
```

while if I type directly `data_all_agg$A[,"50%"]`, I get the values:

```
> data_all_agg$A[,"50%"]
 [1] 0.4620452 0.4874819 0.5084974 0.5524401 0.5282378 0.4586645 0.5726048
 [8] 0.5040240 0.5196544 0.6153615 0.5439682 0.5331080 0.5607132 0.4661196
[15] 0.5572938 0.6014468 0.5490722 0.5181902 0.4968988 0.5233519
```

Also, with `eval()`, it gives the string not the values:

```
for (var_name_counter in c(1:2)) {
        Res <- eval(paste("data_all_agg$", var_names[var_name_counter],"[,\"50%\"]", sep=""))
}

> Res
[1] "data_all_agg$B[,\"50%\"]"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String manipulations like this are usually not the best way to access data.  Nevertheless, if you want to proceed this way, one solution is to use `eval` and `parse`:

```
for (var_name_counter in c(1:2)) {
        Res <- eval(parse(text=paste("data_all_agg$", var_names[var_name_counter],"[,\"50%\"]", sep="")))
}

> Res
 [1] 0.5897688 0.5697550 0.5333134 0.5286540 0.5339315 0.4455871 0.4000211
 [8] 0.5918556 0.2938133 0.5593963 0.5993373 0.5456933 0.5947355 0.4148935
[15] 0.5104526 0.5281240 0.4540751 0.4977381 0.5267636 0.4863866
```

The reason you need to call `parse` is that `eval` expects an expression, not a string, and `parse` will return an expression by parsing a string.  See `?eval` and `?parse` for details.

However, it seems easier to just do something like this, without any string manipulations:

```
> var_names <- c("A", "B")
> for (i in c(1:2)) {
+     Res<-data_all_agg[[var_names[i]]][,"50%"]
+     print(Res)
+ }
 [1] 0.3775643 0.5346113 0.4711610 0.4407886 0.4300827 0.5117041 0.4227422
 [8] 0.5120470 0.5584456 0.5376804 0.4205211 0.6027916 0.5384184 0.5976866
[15] 0.6133554 0.4721133 0.5317935 0.5128450 0.5564370 0.5824520
 [1] 0.5897688 0.5697550 0.5333134 0.5286540 0.5339315 0.4455871 0.4000211
 [8] 0.5918556 0.2938133 0.5593963 0.5993373 0.5456933 0.5947355 0.4148935
[15] 0.5104526 0.5281240 0.4540751 0.4977381 0.5267636 0.4863866
```

Comment: Thanks! I will use your second suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `eval` instead of `get` in order to evaluate the `$` and `[]`s.

Comment: Thanks. But, with eval(), it gives a string of the name not its values. I added the eval() example to the main question.